# Rudin's Functional Analysis Theorem 1.41

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

While I was reading the proof of Theorem 1.41 in Rudin's Functional Analysis, I was stuck in the equation
\begin{equation*}
\pi(\{x:d(x,0)<r\}) = \{u:\rho(u,0)<r\}
\end{equation*}
where $N$ is a closed subspace of a topological vector space $X$, $\pi$ is the quotient map of $X$ onto $X/N$, $d$ is a complete translation-invariant metric on $X$, and $\rho(\pi(x),\pi(y)) = \inf\{d(x-y,z):z\in N\}$.
Specifically, I cannot prove $\{u:\rho(u,0)<r\}\subset \pi(\{x:d(x,0)<r\})$.
I guess that it seems necessary to show that for every $x\in X$ there exists $y\in N$ satisfying $d(x,y) = \inf\{d(x,z):z\in N\}$, but not sure.
Would you give me any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $u$ with $\rho(u,0)<r$, say $u=\pi(y)$. Since
$$
\inf \{d(y,z):z\in N\}<r
$$
there is some $z\in N$ with $d(y,z)<r$. Then $d(y-z,0)<r$ and
$$\pi (y-z)=\pi(y)-\pi(z)=\pi(y)=u,$$ so  taking $x=y-z$ does the trick.

Comment: Why there is some $z\in N$ with $d(y,z)<r$? This is the point I cannot prove.

Comment: @flyingwith Given any bounded non-empty set $A\subset  \mathbb{R}$, if $\inf A <r$, then $r$ is not a lower bound of $A$ (because $\inf A$ is the largest lower bound), which means that there exists some $a\in A$ with $a<r$.

Comment: Could you also say the infimum is attained in $N$ because it is closed?

Comment: @Connor_Tracy No, it false for general Banach spaces (it holds in Hilbert spaces though, by taking orthogonal projections). Here's a counterexample: Let $X:=\{f\in C([0,1]): f(0)=0$. Let $\phi(f):=\int_0^1 f$ (wrt to Lebesgue measure), $N=\ker \phi$ (you can check that $\phi$ is continuous). Assuming you have a function $f\in X$ with $d(f, N)=1=\|f\|$, you can argue that $|\phi(f)|\|g\|\ge |\phi(g)|$ for every $g\in X$. If you consider $f_n(t)=t^\frac{1}{n}$, then $f_n\in X\setminus N$, and you can show using the previous fact that $|\phi(f)|\ge 1$. But $f\in M$, so $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @Connor_Tracy Therefore, using that $\|f\|_\infty =1$, $\phi(f) \le \int _0^1 |f| <1$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain and provide the counter example @Reveillark